# How do i create a custom start activity method in android?

Tags: android, methods, start-activity

I want to create a method to start multiple activities. I have set `setOnClickListener` on every button. I have implemented `onClick()` method that looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.firstActivityButton:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;

        case R.id.secondActivityButton:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;

        //and so on
    }
}
```

I want to use a method in every `case` like this: `startSpecificActivity(FirstActivity.class)` This is my method:

```
public void startSpecificActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), context.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: My error is: `Error:(78, 61) error: cannot find symbol class context`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.firstActivityButton:
            startSpecificActivity(FirstActivity.class);
            break;

        case R.id.secondActivityButton:
            startSpecificActivity(SecondActivity.class);
            break;

        // And so on
    }
}
```

Create method like this where `Class<?>` is a generic class object holder and `?` is a wildcard character:

```
public void startSpecificActivity(Class<?> otherActivityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), otherActivityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And I also encourage to use the `context` or `YourActivityName.this` of current Activity, instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @AlexM. i am glad that i could help , happy coding